# Vue.js: Module parse failed: 'static' in class is unexpected token

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babel

Получаю ошибку при попытке собрать проект на Vue командой **npm run serve** после добавления в зависимости библиотеки yookassa. Проблема с настройкой webpack, видимо. Не хочет парсинг публичные поля классов, ругается на **static**

```
Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

>     static PENDING = 'pending';
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "google-maps": "^4.3.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "tiny-slider": "^2.9.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuex": "3.1.2",
    "yookassa": "^0.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
        '@babel/preset-env'
    ],
}
```

vue.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/assets/scss/style.scss";`
            },
        }
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin( 'html' )
            .tap( args => {
                args[ 0 ].title = 'Here is a Title'
                return args
            } )
    },
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? './'
        : '/',
}
```

Comment: Вопрос переведите

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас отредактирую. Ошибся сайтом - опубликовал на ru, вместо stackoverflow.com